# Vuforia simulator play mode not spawning simulated targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to use the "Simulator" play mode in Vuforia, but having trouble getting *some* simulated targets to spawn.

For the problematic targets, in their 'ImageTargetBehavior' component, they have their type set to **From Image**. Targets that correctly spawn their simulated counter part have their type set to **From Database**.

I see no [note on the documentation for play modes](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/unity-extension/vuforia-play-mode-unity) that seems to suggest this isn't supported. Is this a bug? Or an undocumented limitation? Or do I need to do some additional configuration/]?